# .prop() does not change the checkbox status from inside each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm working on a project where I want to check checkboxes based on matching a regEx Pattern. [MY_JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/masterlup/00e3k7y5/)

I come across a very strange behavior:

```
function checkRegEx() {
    $.each(myjson, function (i, v) {
        var feedname = this.name;
    var regExPat1 = document.getElementById('regExField').value;
    var regExPat = new RegExp(regExPat1, 'gi');
    var matched_bool = regExPat.test(feedname);
    //console.log(matched_bool==true);
    if(matched_bool==true) {
        $("#"+feedname).prop('checked',true);
      //$("#"+feedname).click(); // THIS WORKS STRANGELY
      console.log($("#"+feedname).prop('checked'));
        //console.log("eval TRUE #" + feedname)
    } else {
        $("#"+feedname).prop('checked', false);
        //console.log("eval FALSEE #" + feedname)
    };
  });
  document.getElementById("regExField").focus();
};
```

I can change and read out the status of the checkbox but it won't affect the GUI.
When I use `$("#"+feedname).click();` it works as I would expect. So I'm calling the ID right. I'm working on the latest Chrome. Strangely I found another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimodi/L9x5uhae/). Here the `prop` method works for me. So it can't be a browser issue.

(im aware that jsfiddle uses jquery_edge, that is not the reason why it works there and not in mine- I tested different jquery versions in both jsfiddles)

Any advice. Can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

#### edit

please note that despite calling `var feedname = this.name;` im still refering the ID. (myjsfiddle code some lines above the here posted code)

#### edit 2

I renamed the myjson IDS into "foo".

in the code section

```
var feedname = this.name;
...
            $("<br><input>").attr({
                'id'  : feedname, 
                'type': 'checkbox', 
...
```

Im setting the ID name to the checkbox label name. What am I doing wrong :/

Comment: Your code doesn't need an if statement.  Just use `$('#' + feedname).prop('checked', matched_bool);`.

Comment: true, that optimises the code. but lets see if it solves the issue here, dont thing so.

Comment: updated my jsfiddle. Its still not working. I had the if statement because only using click() had some effect.

Comment: But what is it that you are trying to achieve at first place... Your JSON has `id` and `name` both... but your selector expects an `id` (since you are using `#`).

Comment: Yes comments aren't answers, they are comments...

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/00e3k7y5/16/

Comment: thank you for the input and the great deal of explanaition. I will read it carefully and check an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating element with duplicate ID thus it's not working. The following code will create `<br>` and `input` element with same id *this leads to issue* as ID selector will target first element which is `<br>` thus `.prop()` doesn't have any impact as '
' doesn't have `checked` property.

Here is an demonstration to showcase the problem.

```js
$("<br><input>").attr({
  'id': 'feedname',
  'type': 'checkbox',
}).appendTo('div');

$('#feedname').prop('checked', true);
console.log('feedname id selector targets:', $('#feedname').prop('outerHTML'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

---

Create element with unique ID, rectified code

```
$.each(myjson, function(i, v) {
  var feedname = this.name
  var input = $("<input>").attr({
      'id': feedname,
      'type': 'checkbox',
      'class': 'inp-checkbox',
      'name': 'subscribecal',
      "data-feed": feedname
    }).val(this.id)
    .prop('checked', this.checked);

  $("#calsubscribe").append(
    $("<label>").text(this.name)    
    .prepend(input)
    .prepend('<br>')
    );
});
```

```js
var JSONsettings = [{
    name: "Full_Feed",
    foo: "13",
    checked: false
  }, {
    name: "Trip_Feed",
    foo: "53",
    checked: false
  }, {
    name: "Flight_Feed",
    foo: "27",
    checked: false
  }, {
    name: "Klight_Feed",
    foo: "33",
    checked: false
  }
];

//Removed
//localStorage.setItem("fdsettings", JSON.stringify(JSONsettings));
var myjson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSONsettings));

/*
      0) $.getJson FROM SERVER DB
      1) SET INCOMING JSON TO LOCAL STORAGE
      2) SET UP THE CHECK BOX LIST FROM THE JSON IN LOCAL STORAGE
      3) GATHER NEW JSON SETTINGS ON PRESS AND SAVE TO LOCAL STORAGE
      */
// myjson  // JSONsettings[feeds]
$.each(myjson, function(i, v) {
  var feedname = this.name
  var input = $("<input>").attr({
      'id': feedname,
      'type': 'checkbox',
      'class': 'inp-checkbox',
      'name': 'subscribecal',
      "data-feed": feedname
    }).val(this.id)
    .prop('checked', this.checked);
    
  $("#calsubscribe").append(
   $("<label>").text(this.name)    
    .prepend(input)
    .prepend('<br>')
    );
});

function checkRegEx() {
  var regExPat1 = document.getElementById('regExField').value;
  var regExPat = new RegExp(regExPat1, 'gi');
  $.each(myjson, function(i, v) {
    var feedname = this.name;
    var matched_bool = regExPat.test(feedname);
    $("#" + feedname).prop('checked', matched_bool);
  });
  document.getElementById("regExField").focus();
};

$('#regExField').keyup(checkRegEx).keyup();
```

```css
.inp-checkbox {
  border: 3px solid #444
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="regExField" type="text" value="^f">regEx</input>
<div id="calsubscribe"></div>
```

Comment: Your explanation is more precise especially in the beginning ( and I don't want to add the same explanation again :) ).. OP should select your answer.

Comment: I totally get now what went wrong. Would have taken me ages to find it myself.

Answer (score 3):

> When I use $("#"+feedname).click(); it works as I would expect. So
>   I'm calling the ID right.

You need to get the `id` by

```
var feedname = this.id;
```

`this.name` returns the name property, not the `id`.

Also, you need to ensure that ids are not duplicate (check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/00e3k7y5/16/))

```
  $.each(myjson, function(i, v) {
    var feedname = v.name
    var id = v.foo;
    $("#calsubscribe").append($("<label>").text(feedname).prepend(
      $("<input>").attr({
        'type': 'checkbox',
        'id': "check_"+id,
        'class': 'inp-checkbox',
        'name': 'subscribecal',
        "data-feed": feedname
      }).val(v.id)
      .prop('checked', this.checked)
    ));
  });

  function checkRegEx() {
    $.each(myjson, function(i, v) {
      var regExPat1 = document.getElementById('regExField').value;
      var regExPat = new RegExp(regExPat1, 'gi');
      var matched_bool = regExPat.test(v.name);
      var selector = "#check_" + v.foo;
      $( selector ).prop('checked', matched_bool);
      console.log(selector,regExPat,matched_bool);
    });
    document.getElementById("regExField").focus();
  };
```

**Demo**

```js
var JSONsettings = [{
    name: "Full_Feed",
    foo: "13",
    checked: false
  }, {
    name: "Trip_Feed",
    foo: "53",
    checked: false
  }, {
    name: "Flight_Feed",
    foo: "27",
    checked: false
  }, {
    name: "Klight_Feed",
    foo: "33",
    checked: false
  }

];
var myjson = JSONsettings;

$.each(myjson, function(i, v) {
  var feedname = v.name
  var id = v.foo;
  $("#calsubscribe").append($("<label>").text(feedname).prepend(
    $("<input>").attr({
      'type': 'checkbox',
      'id': "check_" + id,
      'class': 'inp-checkbox',
      'name': 'subscribecal',
      "data-feed": feedname
    }).val(v.id)
    .prop('checked', this.checked)
  ));
});

function checkRegEx() {
  $.each(myjson, function(i, v) {
    var regExPat1 = document.getElementById('regExField').value;
    var regExPat = new RegExp(regExPat1, 'gi');
    var matched_bool = regExPat.test(v.name);
    var selector = "#check_" + v.foo;
    $(selector).prop('checked', matched_bool);
  });
  document.getElementById("regExField").focus();
};

$('#regExField').keyup(function() {
  checkRegEx();
});
```

```css
.inp-checkbox {
  border: 3px solid #444
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="regExField" type="text" value="^f">regEx
<div id="calsubscribe"></div>
```

Comment: @AndreElrico Check Satpal's answer.